# mock trait implementation for concrete struct

Tags: testing, rust, mocking

So I have a function. And I want to test it. It takes a struct as param. And the struct has some trait implemented. This trait has a long running io method. I don't want this io method to actually go fetch data, I want to mock this io method and just return the result. I am a little lost about how this can be done. Here is my try (not working)

```
struct TestStruct {
    a: u32,
    b: u32,
}
pub trait TestTrait {
    fn some_long_running_io_method(&self) -> u32 {
        156
    }
}
fn important_func(a: TestStruct) {
    println!("a: {}", a.some_long_running_io_method());
}
impl TestTrait for TestStruct {
    fn some_long_running_io_method(&self) -> u32 {
        self.a + self.b
    }
}
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use mockall::predicate::*;
    use mockall::*;
    #[cfg(test)]
    mock! {
        pub TestStruct {}
        impl TestTrait for TestStruct {
            fn some_long_running_io_method(&self) -> u32;
        }
    }
    #[test]
    fn test_important_func() {
        let mut mock = MockTestStruct::new();
        mock.expect_some_long_running_io_method()
            .returning(|| 1);
        important_func(mock);
    }
}
```

I obviously get this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/test.rs:35:24
   |
35 |         important_func(mock);
   |         -------------- ^^^^ expected struct `TestStruct`, found struct `MockTestStruct`
   |         |
   |         arguments to this function are incorrect
```

How can I achieve mocking trait methods? 1) One way is to change function param and instead of accepting a concrete struct accept trait. And implement this trait on MockTestStruct. But then we have dynamic dispatching and it hurts the performance. I don't want a performance degrade just for the test. 2) I also tried reimplementing the Trait right where the test is, but conflicting implementations are not allowed in Rust. 3) Make function accept TestStruct or MockTestStruct? Probably not great way either.

Could you please tell me what is the idiomatic way to do it?

Comment: You could try making your `important_func` generic, and then bound the generic type to implementors of your trait. Then you could call it with the mock implementation.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/bounds.html

Comment: Oh great, looks like a nice working solution. You could post it as an answer. If no better answer, I'll accept

Comment: I assume there won't be access to struct attributes. In my particular case it should be fine. Though general solution should have access

Comment: Sure, I am actually not too familiar with the `mockall` crate itself, but feel free to edit my answer to improve it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your function, `important_func` a generic function. You can then use generic bounds to restrict the type to implementors of your trait.

Here is an example with your code:

```rust
struct TestStruct {
    a: u32,
    b: u32,
}
pub trait TestTrait {
    fn some_long_running_io_method(&self) -> u32 {
        156
    }
}

// important_func can now use any type T which implements TestTrait,
// including your mock implementation! 
fn important_func<T: TestTrait>(a: T) {
    println!("a: {}", a.some_long_running_io_method());
}
impl TestTrait for TestStruct {
    fn some_long_running_io_method(&self) -> u32 {
        self.a + self.b
    }
}
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use mockall::predicate::*;
    use mockall::*;
    #[cfg(test)]
    mock! {
        pub TestStruct {}
        impl TestTrait for TestStruct {
            fn some_long_running_io_method(&self) -> u32;
        }
    }
    #[test]
    fn test_important_func() {
        let mut mock = MockTestStruct::new();
        mock.expect_some_long_running_io_method().returning(|| 1);
        important_func(mock);
    }
}
```